# URL regex matching for dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby

I am filtering request URL in which I need to provide boolean value for regex check. I do not know whether it is possible to make such regex or I need to change URLs to follow patterns,

I got confused because I need a match for two like `/cart/{orgSlug}/{cartNameSlug}` & `/cart/{id}` where `slug name` must have at least one character and `id` must be only numeric.

I am taking care of getting the proper URL by splitting by `?` & checking request method as a preliminary test.

Comment: for `/cart/{id}`, I have got `cart\/[0-9]{1,5}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `/cart/{orgSlug}/{cartNameSlug}` you may use:

```
/^\/cart\/[^\/]*[a-z][^\/]*\/[^\/]*[a-z][^\/]*\/?$/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xtHYyG/1)

For `/cart/{id}`, you may use:

```
/^\/cart\/\d+\/?$/i
```

Comment: just incredible :) I removed `/` at the end only.

Comment: You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` (respectively) in Ruby.

Comment: @anubhava what I can do if I want to avoid slug name should not start with a number?

Comment: @ray: Just add `(?1\d)` right after matching `\/` to make it: `^\/cart\/(?!\d)[^\/]*[a-z][^\/]*\/(?!\d)[^\/]*[a-z][^\/]*$`